# How to get html5 video or YouTube video to embed into html email?

Tags: html, email, video, html-email

I have an HTML email put together that includes a video. Everything works except the video won't show up. Then I uploaded the video to YouTube and tried embedding it that way, but I guess Email Providers do not allow Iframes, so that didn't work.

Is there any method that works?

I know you can upload it directly into the email by uploading a attachment, but then it won't be where I need it in my HTML document.

*It works fine both ways outside of the email, in a browser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are reliant on the email client supporting Video playback in emails, and different clients provide different levels of support for this.

There are some places you can look to get a feel for current support levels, although it is worth googling as it is evolving over time. Email campaign engine/service providers often have the best summaries as it is important to their business:

- https://www.campaignmonitor.com/blog/post/3529/html5-video-in-email-an-updated-guide-for-2011/
- https://www.campaignmonitor.com/blog/post/4040/support-for-html-5-elements-in-email
- http://blog.mailup.com/2013/06/video-in-email-support-latest-update-june-2013/

Comment: Thanks. I finally found a few pages that listed the different email providers support. It's pretty much impossible. I've learned the best technique is using a photo back-up to link to the video elsewhere.